# Will the momentum or velocity of two balls be same if they are tied together?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, rotational-kinematics

If two balls of different masses are tied together by a string and then they are thrown on a surface plane in the form shown in figure, will their velocity be same? Or will their momentum be same? This fact is not clear to me. I cannot understand what will be same for both balls. But it seems to me that their velocity will be same, but I don't have ability to prove this fact.

Is there any explanation available related to this topic?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ma5y.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

No, the balls will not necessarily have the same velocity or momentum, as they can rotate around a common center of mass.

Comment: Please akhmeteli, say details...I have not understood this topic yet.

Comment: @user64814: imagine that the constant distance between the balls equals to the length of the string $2R$, the center of mass (the center of the rope) moves with some velocity $v_{cm}$ and the balls rotate around this center of mass with angular velocity $\omega$. The velocities of the balls will differ in this case.